# Why does np.percentile return NaN for high percentiles?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

This code:

```
print len(my_series)
print np.percentile(my_series, 98)
print np.percentile(my_series, 99)
```

gives:

```
14221  # This is the series length
1644.2  # 98th percentile
nan  # 99th percentile?
```

Why does 98 work fine but 99 gives `nan`?

Comment: Is there any NaN values in `my_series`?

Comment: I didn't think there was, but there is. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any justification for this behaviour?

Comment: @Gecko I agree, who came up with this? It literally means _not a number_ and yet it is treated as one by default. Matlab complains if you try to do calculations using NaNs, and gives you the option to ignore it functions like sum(). This seems to imply that NaN = +Inf.

Comment: On recent versions of numpy, this should no longer be the case. In your input has a NaN, then that will "poison" the computation and your output will [always be NaN](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/25769#issuecomment-1929044799).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

np.percentile treats nan's as very high numbers. So the high percentiles will be in the range where you will end up with a nan. In your case, between 1 and 2 percent of your data will be nan's (98th percentile will return you a number (which is not actually the 98th percentile of all the valid values) and the 99th will return you a nan).

To calculate the percentile without the nan's, you can use np.nanpercentile()

So:

```
print(np.nanpercentile(my_series, 98))
print(np.nanpercentile(my_series, 99))
```

**Edit:**
In new Numpy version, `np.percentile` will return nan if nan's are present, so making this problem directly apparent. `np.nanpercentile` still works the same. `

Comment: "np.percentile treats nan's as very high/infinite numbers." This must have changed since you wrote this answer. With numpy 1.26.2, `numpy.percentile([0.0, 1.0, nan], 10)` returns `nan`, but `numpy.percentile([0.0, 1.0, inf], 10)` returns `0.2`. So `nan` is not being treated like it were `inf`. In fact, it seems like it's being treated like it were `-inf`.

Comment: Actually, even that's not correct. On recent versions of numpy, NaN is treated as its own thing. [NaN will "poison" any computation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/25769#issuecomment-1929044799) it's part of. It has no ordering.

Comment: You're correct. I've added the new behaviour of numpy with nan's

Comment: I don't think I actually tested with `np.inf`, so I have removed infinite numbers.